# Correct a definite integral combining two Hermite polynomials and a Gauss function in two reference books

Tags: definite-integrals, hermite-polynomials, derivation-of-formulae

In the celebrated 8th edition (the latest) of I.S. Gradshteyn and I.M. Ryzhik, revised by D. Zwilinger and D. Moll (2015), on page 811 one reads formula 7.374.4 reproduced below:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} H_{2m+n}(ax)H_n(x) \,dx = \sqrt{\pi} \,  2^{-m+\frac{1}{2}} \frac{(2m+n)!}{m!}(a^2-1)^m a^n\qquad (1)$$

$m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, where $H_n$ is the so-called physicist's Hermite polynomial defined by $H_n(x) = (-1)^n e^{x^2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2}$.

The source of the formula is indicated as formula (21) on p. 291 in the well-known "Bateman project" reference book by Erdelyi's et al., *Tables of Integral Transforms*, vol. II. McGraw Hill, New York, 1954.

I checked that there was a misprint by Gradshteyn and al. in reproducing Erdelyi's original formula: they just replaced $e^{-\frac{1}{2} x^2}$ with $e^{-x^2}$ in the LHS integrand. Also Numerical experiments show *both* formulae to be wrong: for example using the following *Mathematica* code:

```
k[a_, c_, m_, n_] := NIntegrate[Exp[-c x^2] HermiteH[2 m + n, a x] HermiteH[n, x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
k[0.01, 1, 3, 4] (* -0.171465 *)
k[0.01, 0.5, 3, 4] (* -901429 *)
l[a_, m_, n_] := Sqrt[Pi] 2^(-m + 1/2) Factorial[2 m + n]/Factorial[m] (a^2 - 1)^m  a^n
l[0.01,3,4] (* -0.00189444 *)
```

I found that the correct formula in Gradshteyn et al. should be instead:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} H_{2m+n}(ax)H_n(x) \,dx = \sqrt{\pi} \,  2^{n} \frac{(2m+n)!}{m!}(a^2-1)^m a^n\qquad (2)$$

which is quite a difference from the published formula.

Numerical experiments confirm this:

```
p[a_, m_, n_] := Sqrt[Pi] 2^n Factorial[2 m + n]/Factorial[m] (a^2 - 1)^m  a^n
p[0.01,3,4] (* -0.171465  = k[0.01, 1, 3, 4], as expected *)
```

I have seen no errata anywhere for this formula. Yet, notwithstanding the authoritative references, $(2)$ works and $(1)$ does not.

Question: Either prove the corrected version (2) of the formula or prove that I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us denote:

$$I_{m,n}(a) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} H_{2m+n}(ax)H_n(x) \, dx$$

As

$$H_{2m+n}(ax) = (2m+n)! \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{m+\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!\,(2m+n-2k)!} (2ax)^{2m+n-2k} \tag{3},$$

by integrating $(3)$, we obtain:

$$I_{m,n}(a) = (2m+n)! \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{m+\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!\,(2m+n-2k)!} (2a)^{2m+n-2k} J_{2m+n-2k,n}(a) $$

in which

$$J_{r,n}(a) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^r e^{-x^2} H_n(x) dx $$

Now the integral $J_{r,n}(a) $ for $r$ positive integral can be obtained from the $n^{th}$ coefficient of the  (finite) expansion of $x^{r}$ in a Hermite polynomial basis. The classic inverse expansion formula:

$$ x^r = \frac{r!}{2^r} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{\frac{r}{2}}\rfloor}\frac{1}{k! (r-2k)!}H_{r-2k}(x)$$

therefore yields, for $r-2k=n$, considering the normalizing coefficient $2^n n! \sqrt{\pi}$:

\begin{align}J_{r,n}(a) &= \frac{r!}{2^{r}\,\frac{r-n}{2}!\,n!} \times 2^n n! \sqrt{\pi} \\
&= \frac{r!}{2^{r-n}\,\frac{r-n}{2}!} \sqrt{\pi} \\
\end{align}
for $r \geq n$ and $J_{r,n}(a)=0$ otherwise, by an obvious argument on polynomial degrees.

Whence:

\begin{align}
I_{m,n}(a) &= 2^n a^{2m+n} (2m+n)! \sqrt{\pi} \, \frac{1}{m!}\sum_{k=0}^{m} \frac{(-\frac{1}{a^2})^k}{k!\,}  \frac{m!}{(m-k)!}\\
&= \sqrt{\pi} 2^n a^{2m+n} \frac{(2m+n)!}{m!} \, \frac{(a^2-1)^{m}}{a^{2m}} \quad \text{ by the binomial theorem}\\
&= \sqrt{\pi} 2^n \frac{(2m+n)!}{m!}  \, (a^2-1)^{m} a^{n} 
\end{align}

which is $(2)$.